# What directory is an SMSS SQL Studio project stored in?

Tags: sql-server

What directory is an SMSS SQL Studio project stored in?

I can't find where and how SMSS SQL Studio stores projects

For example I have various databases.

[image]

Is each stored in a separate directory/subdirectory. Where?

I've seen two suggestions and I haven't see anything I can determine to be resembling what might be the database files.

I don't see them here, though I can't even access the directory even after closing SMSS.

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL>cd data
Access is denied.

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL>
```

And I can't see them here either.

```
C:\Users\harvey\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio>dir /ad
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is B411-D580

 Directory of C:\Users\harvey\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio

03/04/2018  11:21 PM    <DIR>          .
03/04/2018  11:21 PM    <DIR>          ..
28/06/2015  08:20 PM    <DIR>          Code Snippets
28/06/2015  08:20 PM    <DIR>          Settings
17/06/2015  09:55 AM    <DIR>          Templates
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               5 Dir(s)     320,012,288 bytes free

C:\Users\harvey\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio>
```

Comment: You can right click..properties..take it off 'read only', then you can CD into that data subdirectory, and DIR. If you want to copy the MDF and LDF files, you might get an error that the file is open, you can then do  `net stop mssqlserver` and copy it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image in your question is not a project. It is SSMS Object Explorer, a hierarchical view of objects on the database server you are connected to.

The default location of SSMS projects is `C:\Users\<your-user>\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio`.

Comment: okay so where does the database server  access the databases from?

Comment: Each database has it's own set of data (.mdf and .ndf file extension) and log files (.ldf file extension). These are all managed by the SQL Server service. The default location for database data files on your box looks to be `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data`.

Comment: But as my question shows, I can't access that directory

Comment: You need to be an admin on the box to access the folder. But the real question is why you need to. The SQL Sever services manages the files.

Comment: I guess I shouldn't put my own notes there in that directory, but when I make a database and I have tables I want to write comments about  I see no room to anywhere. The closest I can do is make a procedure and click execute to save it.

Comment: You can add notes and other description information as extended properties. Right-click on the table in SSMS Object explorer Properties-->Extended Properties. Then enter properties as name/value pairs (e.g. "Notes", "This table stores data").

Comment: that is really limiting as a place to write notes, you can only write one line in any value of a name-value pair.  So any time I want to write a new line in i'd have to make a new name-value pair

Comment: @barlop, clock the ellipsis button (`...`) to the right of the value to enter multiple lines.